# Phonegap 3.4 camera imported but reference error when accessing navigator.camera

Tags: android, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a PhoneGap 3.4 application and trying to just get the basics of taking a photo in android.
 
When I run `cordova plugin ls` in my project directory I can see that **org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.0 "Camera"** is added, and my manifest file has 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" \>` 
added to it.
 
whenever I try to change to call
`navigator.camera.getPicture()`
 I get back a **"ReferenceError: Camera is not defined."**
 
I read online there was 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`,
 and I tried adding that but I was still unsuccessful.
I've been at this for a couple days now and I can't seem to get it to work. First time poster so sorry if I couldn't do all the good formatting :P

Comment: How you installed camera plugin?

Comment: try to remove the camera plugin and reinstall the same. Did you install the camera plugin or was it added by default? Generally after phonegap 3.x you need to add most of the native features ( camera, contacts, vibrator etc) manually.

Comment: I added the camera plugin by using `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`